# Merging one attribute for all records into array using Jbuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jbuilder

I have a collection of products, each has_many tags. I'd like to combine the name of all tags so that I have an array of all tag names.

Desired Output:

```
{
    "title": "Product1", 
    "tags": ["name1", "name2", "name3"]
}
```

My current jbuilder is giving me:

```
{Products: [{
    "title": "Product1",
    "tags":[
        {"tag1":
           {"name": "name1"}
         },
        {"tag2": 
           {"name": "name2"}
         },
        {"tag3":
           {"name": "name3"}
         }
      ]
}]}
```

My current jbuilder.

```
json.array! @products do |product|
    json.title product.title
    json.tags product.tags do |tag|
        json.name tag.name
    end
end
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried `json.tags product.tags` without the `do` block?

Comment: I still get nested tag objects. Essentially, I need an array of just the tag names to be equal to json.tags.

Comment: ok, maybe try `json.tags product.tags.map(&:name)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just extract the tag name from each tag!

```
json.array! @products do |product|
    json.title product.title
    json.tags product.tags.map(&:name)
end
```

If tag is a relation, you can make this even more efficient using `pluck` instead

```
json.array! @products do |product|
    json.title product.title
    json.tags product.tags.pluck(:name)
end
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Pluck is what I was looking for!